# AngularJs passing $http.get to video source tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, video

I am trying to get my app controller load a fullscreen background video using $http.get and then on success subsequently pass that data into a video source tag. I figured this was the best way so that I could also pass a variable loading to a preloader div obstructing the view of the video, that will fadeout once the video is loaded using ng-show="loading".

### app.js

```
    app.controller('main', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.loading = true;

    $http.get('assets/bg.mp4')
    .success(function (data) {

      $scope.video = data;
      console.log("video loaded");

    })
    .catch(function (err) {

      console.log("error occured");

    })
    .finally(function () {

      $scope.loading = false;

    });
```

### index.html

```
<body ng-controller="main">
  <div id="preloader" ng-show="loading"></div>
  <video autoplay id="bg" loop>
    <source src="{{ video }}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body>
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KJFU.png)

when I open the file the preloader fades out correctly but I am unsure why file is not resolving. I am almost certain I am going about this the wrong way but, being new the Angular I am unsure how to go about it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: for binding of sources, you the following correct will work for you: ng-src instead of src

Comment: ng-src didnt work for me it still didnt resolve the file source unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

try to use `ng-src="expression"` instead of `src="{{expression}}"`

Comment: I did try this and in both cases ng-src="{{video}}" and ng-src="video" had the same results